# Java - Use KeyPressed to change position of rectangle in another class

Tags: java, key, listener

I am creating a brick breaker game, and I have a class that will display all the elements, which is fine.

I then have a key listener class that performs the actions. Essentially I want to access the shape I drew in my class and change the position of it using the key listener class.

I tested it with the system out, and it does change the value of X, but it doesn't physically change it (in the gui). I am using setter and getter methods.

I **think** the problem is that the only way for me to use `shapes[]` in my keyboard class is to make a new one, so it isn't using the one I make in my paintComponent but rather the one I made in my key listener? I am a bit lost as to how I can access my objects and apply a keyboard action to it.

-

```
public class GameView extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

//additional code is here (not related to issue)


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {



            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                    g.fillRect(1,1,410,410);

                    shapeClass[1].draw(g);

                }
            }
        }
```

Now in my keyboard listener class

```
public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[5];

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            if(shapes[1].getX() >= 400) {
                shapes[1].setX(400);
            }
            else {
                moveRight();
                repaint();

            }

        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            if(shapes[1].getX() < 0) {
                shapes[1].setX(0);
            }
            else {
                moveLeft();
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        play = true;
        shapes[1].incrementX();
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        play = true;
        shapes[1].decrementX();
    }


}
```

Comment: Seems like you're creating a new `Rectangle` with constant values every time the key is pressed.

Comment: But if i repaint, shouldn't that make make it move?

Comment: Not if you keep resetting the rectangle by creating a new one using the values it started with. Each time you try to move, the rectangle is replaced with a new one, and the new rectangle is adjusted/moved. Next time you press a key to move again, it'll replace the adjusted rectangle (the one you just moved) with a new rectangle that uses the initial location. You have a few options to fix this, the easiest being to add a null check: `if(shapes[1] == null) { shapes[1] = new Rectangle(180,390,50,8,0); }`. Ensures the rectangle is only created if not already created.

Comment: Would this be a check within my keypressed? Or would this be replacing my initial creation of the object. Not quite sure why i'd need a null check.

Comment: Oh, I see. Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `Shape[]` from both `GameView` and `MyKeyListener` without making your array `public static` by using dependency injection:

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[5];
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(180,390,50,8,0);
shapes[2] = new Circle (199,365,10,0);

GameView view = new GameView(shapes);
MyKeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener(shapes);
```

You'd give each class a constructor to accept the shapes, then have them hold a reference to the shapes:

```
class GameView {
    private Shape[] shapes;

    public GameView(Shape[] shapes) {
        this.shapes = shapes;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g.fillRect(1,1,410,410);

                shapes[1].draw(g);
                shapes[2].draw(g);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyKeyListener {
    private Shape[] shapes;

    public MyKeyListener(Shape[] shapes) {
        this.shapes = shapes;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
           if(shapes[1].getX() >= 410) {
               shapes[1].setX(410);
           } else {
               moveRight();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I removed a few lines of code, such as `shapes[1] = new Rectangle(180,390,50,8,0);` which would reset the rectangle every time you pressed a key.

---

If your `MyKeyListener` object is created in your `GameView`, you could create the `Shape[]` inside `GameView`:

```
class GameView {
    private Shape[] shapes;
    private MyKeyListener listener;

    public GameView() {
        shapes[1] = ...;
        shapes[2] = ...;
        listener = new MyKeyListener(shapes);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to create it where you instantiate `GameView` and `MyKeyListener`. For example, if you instantiate them in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[5];;
    shapes[1] = ...;
    shapes[2] = ...;
    GameView view = new GameView(shapes);
    MyKeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener(shapes);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you initiating my shape object? I would have thought the first line within the GameView class?

Comment: @beastcplusplus Check the edits at the bottom, let me know if there's any other confusion

Comment: Sorry, you're explanations have nothing wrong with them. But it seem's I cant progress. I tried to take into account what you said, but since you can't see all my classes/ and methods I cant test your's exactly the way you want me to. Could you perhaps take a look at my code and let me know why I still persist with the same problem?

Comment: Infact ill add the other classes to the main post, one second @Vince Emigh

Comment: I added the few extra classes I didn't include but i didn't update how i applied the move function since my issue was the same

Comment: @beastcplusplus I'll take a look, give me a second

Comment: Nvm i fixed tyvm

Comment: @beastcplusplus Inside `MyKeyListener`, create a constructor as shown in the example. Then, remove the first line I side `keyPressed`. Finally, inside `GameView`, pass `shapes` to `new MyKeyListener()`

Comment: @beastcplusplus No problem, don't forget to up vote and mark as accepted answer (click the checkmark) if this solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you set your shapes[] to public static, you can access them from any class. So,  do something like this.

```
public class GameView extends JCompnent implements ActionListener {

    public static Shape[] shapes = new Shape[5];
```

Then from there, you can access them from another class by typing:

```
GameView.shapes.someShapeMethod();
```

Good luck, and cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I can now access the object but it seems the actual rectangle still does not move.

Comment: What exactly does the play boolean control?

Comment: Oh at the moment it doesn't have a function, its just for future reference. Initially its set to false but i set it to true but it has no effect on the rest

Comment: I've noticed now from this update in code, my output when i press right is 180 -> 200, then if i press right arrow again, it prints 180->200. So it is resetting.

Comment: Make it so shapes[1] = new Rectangle(); is OUTSIDE of the keyPressed method. Initialize it under when you first create the Shape array.

Comment: Yes, i have removed all my shape initializations and creations of the object from within the key class, my only shape creation is within the paintComponent now and initialization is how u first mentioned to make it public.

Comment: Or, based on the code you already have, just delete it from the keyPressed method.

Comment: You made it so whenever you call shapes in the keyPressed, it ACTUALLY calls GameView.shapes[1] right?

Comment: I believe so, like in my code above in the post correct? https://pastebin.com/kC13tU3g

Comment: Yes, correct. Does it do the same in the moveLeft and moveRight methods?

Comment: Well i've done it like this: https://pastebin.com/zPL0NLJN i included my getter and setter methods.

Comment: So, when you use the MyKeyListener class in the GameView, do you create an instance of MyKeyListener, or do you use it statically?